# How to share a specific utils function between different files in nodeJS to keep track of 3 MongoDB collection names

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have to keep track of three collection names for three MongoDB collection.
One to insert a json data from an API. The second to consume the data in my own API (this is necessary because I have to avoid the calls  restrictions to the API provider). And the third to drop the "old" collection. And this will be repeating every 5 seconds endless. If the following code stay together in one file is no problem, but I have to separate them in 3 different files/modules. My question is what approach is the right one to make it work in `NodeJS` and to keep the names consistently? At this point, when I run the code the `getLetter()` it just start over and return the same object every iteration. Here the most important part of code as pseudo code. If you have some experience please help. Thank you!

***getLetter.js*** utils file

```
// return each time the next object with three different letters as value:

const XYZ = { I: 'X', II: 'Y', III: 'Z' };
const YZX = { I: 'Y', II: 'Z', III: 'X' };
const ZXY = { I: 'Z', II: 'X', III: 'Y' };
let nr = 1;

function getLetter() {
  let obj;
  if (nr == 1) {
    obj = XYZ;
    nr++;
    return obj;
  } else if (nr == 2) {
    obj = YZX;
    nr++;
    return obj;
  } else if (nr == 3) {
    obj = ZXY;
    nr = 1;
    return obj;
  }
}
```

***server.js*** file

```
function intervalFunction() {
  insertCollection();
  consumeCollection();
  dropCollection();
}
if (isInserted  && isDropped) {
  setInterval(intervalFunction, 5000);
}
```

***insertCollection.js** Pseudo code to insert the "new" collection in MongoDB*

```
let newCollectionName = `collection_${getLetter().III}`;
if (isNewCollectionNameInserted) isInserted = true;
```

***consumeCollection.js** Pseudo code to deliver the "actual" collection* (after aggregation) in an API endpoint

```
let actualCollection = `collection_${getLetter().II}`;
```

***dropCollection.js** Pseudo code to drop the "old" collection from MongoDB*

```
let oldCollection = `collection_${getLetter().I}`;
if (isOldCollectionDropped) isDropped = true;
```

Comment: Please update the question with a [mre].

Comment: why can't you just grab the value of `getLetter()` in server.js once and pass it into the other functions?

Comment: @devdev_dev, Because every time we call getLetter(), this will start over and have for every caller different obj. The problem is how to share the same obj and update it only once every 5 seconds. So we need a central obj witch will offer same data for all callers when is called (executed) and update data every 5 seconds. One solution is to kepp this data in a separate collection, but this will be 4 extra network traffic each time

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the problem but I will try to help:

instead of 3 modules (insert, consume, drop) I would use 2:

1. update collection
2. consume collection

**getLetter.js** utils file

```js
    let index = 0;
    const letters = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'];

    function getLetter() {
      return letters[index];
    }
    
    function updateIndex() {
      index = (index + 1) % 3;
    }
    
    console.log(getLetter()); // X
    updateIndex();
    console.log(getLetter()); // Y
```

Then you can do something like that:

**server.js** file

```js
function intervalFunction() {
  updateCollection();
  consumeCollection();
}

setInterval(intervalFunction, 5000);
```

**updateCollection.js** file

```js
updateCollection() {
  updateIndex();
}
```

**consumeCollection.js** file

```js
let actualCollection = `collection_${getLetter()}`;
```

This way you won't have to delete the collection every time.

Hope it is what you looked for.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, you should not be storing 'state' in your nodejs code.  Push that off to a service built for that.

For your example, one approach (among many solutions) would be to use Redis to store a lock, and key/value of those configs..

combo of using `redis` and `redis-lock`

```
//insertCollection ....

const client = require("redis").createClient(),
    lock = require("redis-lock")(client);

async insertTheNewColleciton(collectionName) {
    const value = await client.get(collectionName);
    if(!value) {
        // insert new collection into mongo

        //add key to redis.
        await client.set(collectionName, 'i-exist');
    }
}

async doTheInsert(collectionName){
    await client.connect(); //will need to configure the connectivity
    
    console.log("Asking for lock");
    let done;
    try {
        done = await lock(collectionName); //lock on the collection name.   (you can also acquire a lock, with a time out)
        console.log("Lock acquired");
        await insertTheNewColleciton() // Some async task

        console.log("Releasing lock now");

    finally{
        if (done) { // even if an exception is thrown, or not.. release lock.
            await done()
        }
    }
}
```

Same Pattern for the Other Method...  acquire the lock, do some work, close the lock

This way.. your 'server.js' can actually put the methods in different api endpoints... and you call call each one separately or together.  And now you can run this on multiple servers, and Redis will be to common 'state' store.

Not the only answer, but one possible solution.